# How to set/create records in associations in Sequelize? (many to many relation)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use the parent.addChild() method Sequelize provides, but for some reason it can't recongise that function and throws and error on me.

I read a bunch of other questons here and they all mention that these methods are added to the model. I read the whole docs, re-read [the part](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/) containing the information I need, but just I can't get this thing to run... I can't see what I'm doing wrong here, can you guys give me a hand?

```
// Models
const Person = Conn.define('person', {
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

const Post = Conn.define('post', {
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false        
    }
});

// Relationships 
Person.belongsToMany(Post, {
    as: 'person',
    through: 'people_posts',
    foreignKey: 'person_id'
});
Post.belongsToMany(Person, {
    as: 'post',
    through: 'people_posts', 
    foreignKey: 'post_id'
});


Conn.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {

    const firstName = Faker.name.firstName();
    const lastName = Faker.name.lastName();

    return Person.create({
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName
    })
    .then(() => {
        return Post.create({
            title: `Title by ${firstName}`,
            content: 'Content' 
        });         
    }).then(() => {
        const person = Person.findOne({ where: { firstName: firstName }});
        const post = Post.findOne({ where: { content: "Content" }})

        return post.addPerson(person);
        // this gives me: Unhandled rejection TypeError: post.addPerson is not a function
    });
});
```